# MySQL Query - Multiple Joins

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a table, t1, that is full of metrics from operators identified by a key, I'll call it PID, and I am trying to retrieve a status column from another table, t3, that identifies operators by a different type of key, I'll call this SID. The problem is an additional table, t2, is required to map the SIDs to PIDs.

I need to retrieve all the information in t3 and return null if there is no data available for the operators in t1.

The tables are structured as:

```
Table 1
----------------------------
| PID | ... | ... | Date   |
----------------------------
| 1   | ... | ... | 9/09/19|
----------------------------
| 1   | ... | ... | 9/10/19|
----------------------------
| 2   | ... | ... | 9/09/19|
----------------------------
| 2   | ... | ... | 9/10/19|
----------------------------

Table 2
-----------------
|  SID  |  PID  | 
-----------------
|   01  |   1   | 
-----------------
|   02  |   1   | 
-----------------
|   10  |   2   | 
-----------------
|   11  |   2   |
-----------------

Table 3
----------------------------
|  SID  | Status | Date    |
----------------------------
|   01  |   P    | 9/09/19 |
----------------------------
|   02  |   P    | 9/10/19 |
----------------------------
```

I've tried a few queries and from what I read, I need to do a LEFT JOIN since I need to keep everything from the first table and return null if no rows match the first. One thing I am not sure is since can be multiple SIDs to a single PID and I am not sure how the query behaves. All SID statuses should be uniform if they fall under the same PID so does it just return first match?

My current query:

```sql
SELECT t1.*,  t3.Status
FROM Table1 t1,
  LEFT JOIN Table2 t2
    ON t1.PID = t2.PID
  LEFT JOIN Table3 t3
    ON t2.SID = t3.SID AND t1.Date = t3.Date
ORDER BY t1.PID, t1.Date
```

So far, the closest thing to what I want is the query above. I've tried to modify pieces of it but the issue is that it seems to be leaving out any PIDs that do not have an associated status.

I am expecting to see something like:

```
--------------------------------------
| PID | ... | ... |  Date  |  Status |
--------------------------------------
| 1   | ... | ... | 9/09/19|    P    |
--------------------------------------
| 1   | ... | ... | 9/10/19|    P    |
--------------------------------------
| 2   | ... | ... | 9/09/19|   null  | 
--------------------------------------
| 2   | ... | ... | 9/10/19|   null  |     
--------------------------------------
```

However I am getting a result that leaves out rows with PID 2. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Your query looks fine, apart from a traling comma here: `FROM Table1 t1,`, but that looks more like a typo (otherwise you would get a syntax error), and records with `PID 2` should show up in the results, with `NULL` status as expected.

Comment: I get results with PID 2: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/51snAkQhx229KNqnuXS1hJ/0

Comment: I don't see anything wrong other than the comma at the end of line 2.  Are you sure there's no `WHERE` clause?

Comment: @Eric Thank you! There was a WHERE clause added (t3.Status != 'X') to remove unwanted statuses which removes null I'm assuming. I forgot to add that on there but that was definitely it.

Comment: Yes, this will remove nulls since most operators evaluate to null if one operand is null. And a where-clause evaluated to null is treated as if it evaluated to false, thus removing the rows.

Answer (score 0):

An additional WHERE clauses was added that I overlooked. Thanks to @Eric for helping point that out.